# Android Confirm Binding to Text To Speech Engine

Tags: android, binding, text-to-speech

I can successfully implement the `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener` and receive an int value for `TextToSpeech.SUCCESS` when the `onInit()`-method is called. If I place code inside the `onInit()`-method to invoke speech, the TTS object successfully plays the utterance, but there is noticeable delay of several seconds.

If I immediately use code to invoke speech outside of the `onInit()`-method, I receive a warning message in LogCat, which tells that the TTS object is not bound to a TTS engine, and no utterance is heard. However, if I wait for 5 seconds or so, and use code outside of the `onInit()` method, I do not receive the binding warning and the utterance is heard.

**1.** Why is there no error thrown in the `onInit()` after the return code is `TextToSpeech.SUCCESS` (I am not waiting when I'm invoking speech here)?

**2.** The `TextToSpeech.SUCCESS` return code seems to *not* indicate that the TTS object is bound to the TTS engine - Is there another method to use to check successful binding?

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        voice = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status = TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    voice.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                    voice.speak("I successfully talk here, after a delay.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);                        
                }
            }
        });

        voice.speak("Apparently, I'm not bound to the TTS engine.  Maybe too soon to talk.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

LogCat is showing a define lag between the "voice" object completing instantiation and my attempt to use it.

```
11-07 21:45:11.534: D/MyActiviy(12350): About to instantiate voice  
11-07 21:45:11.574: I/TextToSpeech(12350): Sucessfully bound to com.google.android.tts  
11-07 21:45:11.574: D/MyActiviy(12350): About to speak outside of onInit  
11-07 21:45:11.574: W/TextToSpeech(12350): speak failed: not bound to TTS engine  
11-07 21:45:11.574: D/MyActiviy(12350): Should have spoken  
11-07 21:45:11.694: I/Adreno-EGL(12350): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13  
11-07 21:45:11.734: D/OpenGLRenderer(12350): Enabling debug mode 0  
11-07 21:45:12.114: I/TextToSpeech(12350): Connected to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}  
11-07 21:45:12.114: I/TextToSpeech(12350): Set up connection to ComponentInfo{com.google.android.tts/com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService}  
11-07 21:45:12.124: D/MyActiviy(12350): voice onInit called.  
11-07 21:45:12.124: D/MyActiviy(12350): voice onInit status returned SUCCESS
```

Comment: A status of SUCCESS in the onInit callback means that you're bound to the TTS engine and can make speak calls. Why would you expect the second speak call here to work if the onInit callback has not occurred yet?

Comment: This is the issue.  The object "voice" is instantiated with the constructor calling onInit prior to my attempt to speak outside of the onInit method.  Please see the LogCat entires I added below the code.  The second line seems to indicate a successful bind, and the fourth line says not bound. If the object needs time to successfully complete setup process, how can I tell when it is truly bound to the engine and good to go?

Comment: It's bound after you receive the callback. The binding process occurs asynchronously, so you can't just make a call immediately after returning from the constructor. You have to wait for the initialization callback.